# Retornar registros de acordo com porcentagem no sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Boa noite, 
Preciso fazer um select que me retorne somente os registros que foram pagos mais de 60% das parcelas.

Criei uma tabela com a seguinte estrutura:

```
CREATE TABLE PARCELAS(
IDPARCELAS INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
IDFINANCIAMENTO INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES FINANCIAMENTO(IDFINANCIAMENTO),
NUMERO INT NOT NULL,
VALOR_PARCELA DECIMAL(18,2) NOT NULL,
DATA_VENCIMENTO DATE NOT NULL,
DATA_PAGAMENTO DATE 
);
```

Resultado do select:

```
1 213 2 1 2333.33 2019-07-25 2019-07-25
2 214 2 2 2333.33 2019-08-25 2019-08-25
3 215 2 3 2333.33 2019-09-25 2019-09-25
4 216 2 4 2333.33 2019-10-25 2019-10-25
5 217 2 5 2333.33 2019-11-25 2019-11-25
6 218 2 6 2333.33 2019-12-25 2019-12-25
7 219 2 7 2333.33 2020-01-25 2020-01-25
8 220 2 8 2333.33 2020-02-25 2020-02-25
9 221 2 9 2333.33 2020-03-25 2020-03-25
10 222 2 10 2333.33 2020-04-25 2020-04-25
11 223 2 11 2333.33 2020-05-25 2020-05-25
12 224 2 12 2333.33 2020-06-25 2020-06-25
13 225 2 13 2333.33 2020-07-25 2020-07-25
14 226 2 14 2333.33 2020-08-25 2020-08-25
15 227 2 15 2333.33 2020-09-25 2020-09-25
16 228 3 1 3000.00 2019-07-25 NULL
17 229 3 2 3000.00 2019-08-25 NULL
18 230 3 3 3000.00 2019-09-25 NULL
19 231 3 4 3000.00 2019-10-25 NULL
20 232 3 5 3000.00 2019-11-25 NULL
21 233 3 6 3000.00 2019-12-25 NULL
22 234 3 7 3000.00 2020-01-25 NULL
23 235 3 8 3000.00 2020-02-25 NULL
24 236 3 9 3000.00 2020-03-25 NULL
25 237 3 10 3000.00 2020-04-25 NULL
26 238 3 11 3000.00 2020-05-25 NULL
27 239 3 12 3000.00 2020-06-25 NULL
28 240 3 13 3000.00 2020-07-25 NULL
29 241 3 14 3000.00 2020-08-25 NULL
30 242 3 15 3000.00 2020-09-25 NULL
31 243 4 1 2200.00 2020-04-25 1900-01-01
32 244 4 2 2200.00 2020-05-25 1900-01-01
33 245 4 3 2200.00 2020-06-25 1900-01-01
34 246 4 4 2200.00 2020-07-25 1900-01-01
35 247 4 5 2200.00 2020-08-25 1900-01-01
36 248 4 6 2200.00 2020-09-25 1900-01-01
37 249 4 7 2200.00 2020-10-25 1900-01-01
38 250 4 8 2200.00 2020-11-25 1900-01-01
39 251 4 9 2200.00 2020-12-25 1900-01-01
40 252 4 10 2200.00 2021-01-25 1900-01-01
41 253 4 11 2200.00 2021-02-25 1900-01-01
42 254 4 12 2200.00 2021-03-25 1900-01-01
43 255 4 13 2200.00 2021-04-25 1900-01-01
44 256 4 14 2200.00 2021-05-25 1900-01-01
45 257 4 15 2200.00 2021-06-25 1900-01-01
46 258 5 1 1266.66 2020-01-25 2020-01-25
47 259 5 2 1266.66 2020-02-25 2020-02-25
48 260 5 3 1266.66 2020-03-25 2020-03-25
49 261 5 4 1266.66 2020-04-25 NULL
50 262 5 5 1266.66 2020-05-25 NULL
51 263 5 6 1266.66 2020-06-25 NULL
52 264 5 7 1266.66 2020-07-25 NULL
53 265 5 8 1266.66 2020-08-25 NULL
54 266 5 9 1266.66 2020-09-25 NULL
55 267 5 10 1266.66 2019-07-25 NULL
56 268 5 11 1266.66 2019-08-25 NULL
57 269 5 12 1266.66 2019-09-25 NULL
58 270 5 13 1266.66 2019-10-25 NULL
59 271 5 14 1266.66 2019-11-25 NULL
60 272 5 15 1266.66 2019-12-25 NULL
```

Onde nessa tabela possuem 60 registros. Eu preciso trazer somente os registros onde a 3ª coluna é 2 e 4, pois nelas foram pagas mais de 60% das parcelas. Uma parcela que não foi paga está com a data de pagamento como NULL, como posso fazer isso com select sem utilização de procedures.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: O que você salva nesse campo NUMERO? Ele fica com o valor 2 4?

Comment: Velho, coloca o select que tu fez tambem. Uma duvida, tu faz um `insert` de todas as parcelas e depois tu faz um `update` no registro da parcela paga?

Comment: @DanielMendes esse 2 e 4 é uma FK de outra tabela, chamada financiamento, onde o financiamento 2 tem essas parcelas e o 4 tb

Comment: @Tmilitino mas a minha duvida é essa, eu nao sei de que forma eu poderia fazer o select, fiz o insert na mao, direto adicionei ja com os campos nulos

Comment: O que não entendo, é que você exibe 7 colunas como resultado, mas sua tabela só tem 6 campos. Tudo aparenta que sua query é muito simples de ser criada, mas é necessário compreender esses dados.

Comment: so quero o `select` que usou pra trazer esse resultado

Comment: @DanielMendes a primeira coluna é somente a quantidade de registros, da segunda em diante que são os campos da minha tabela

Comment: @Tmilitino select * from parcelas

Comment: Ah, ok. A seria a quarta coluna no caso então que deve ter o valor 2 e 4? Seria 2 e 4 mesmo? Ou seria 2 OU (OR) 4?

Comment: @DanielMendes eu dei um exemplo, eu preciso retornar somente os financiamentos (coluna 2) que tenha 60% das parcelas pagas, ou seja, se cada um deles tem 15 parcelas, eu tenho que trazer todos que tenha pago pelo menos 9 parcelas, que seria 2 e 4, pois 2 e 4 tem as 15 parcelas pagas, o 3 nao tem nenhuma e a 5 tem 3, entendeu?

Comment: Uma pergunta básica, que não dá para depreender do que você escreveu: Qual campo dá a informação da quantidade de parcelas efetivamente pagas? Ou como posso determinar tal quantidade a partir dos dados de sua tabela (juntamente com os dados de exemplo que você postou)? Supondo que o segundo campo de seu select seja IDFINANCIAMENTO ele não se repete, pelo menos em seu exemplo. Tem também o que já foi perguntado: sua tabela tem 6 campos mas seu exemplo de select tem 7 campos.

Comment: Vamos la, de novo, o primeiro campo é somente o numero de registros da tabela, é o numero das linhas, a coluna idfinanfiamento nesse caso seria a 3 coluna. Para saber se ela ta paga o campo data de pagamento nao pode estar como null

Comment: cara entendi agora, da uma reformulada na pergunta que ficou muito confuso

Answer (score 0):

Segue solução:

```
select idfinanciamento
,count(IDPARCELAS)
,count(data_pagamento)
,count(data_pagamento)*100/count(IDPARCELAS) as percentual_pago
from parcelas
where idfinanciamento in
      (select distinct idfinanciamento from parcelas where data_pagamento is not null)
group by idfinanciamento
having  count(data_pagamento)*100/count(IDPARCELAS) >= 60
```